# Как отсортировать данные в бинарном файле?

Tags: c++, сортировка

У меня есть класс, который хранит всю информацию о работнике: имя, номер карты, зарплата и т.д.

```
class employee{
   int cardNo;
   char name[80];
   int salary;
}
```

У меня есть функции, которые записывают/читают в файл. Мне нужно отсортировать информацию по номеру карты, имени работника и вывести это, и я застрял здесь... Я перечитал несколько форумов и мне кажется что это можно решить так: сохранить информацию в массив, и затем отсортировать его. Но я не понимаю как искать столбец с именами или столбец с номерами карт. Использовать `seekg()`?